# Make Graphics2D Text Blink with Delay

Tags: java, timer, graphics2d

I have a draw method drawing a String to the screen using a Graphics2D object. I set up an if statement in the draw method to make the text draw every second (blinking effect), but the text will draw for a second, then not draw only one frame and continue drawing again. I would like for it to draw for a second, then not draw for a second and so on.

Here is the method -

```
long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - blinkTimer) / 1000000;
    if(elapsed < 1000){
        // g.drawString("",x,y); Draw String Here
    }else{
        blinkTimer = System.nanoTime();
    }
```

blinkTimer is initialized in the constructor as `System.nanoTime();`

I would like to accomplish this without using the Java Timer object. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this without using the Timer class? It's possible, but your current issue is you need a second timer for the color inversion duration.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There is added flexibility with my own timer

Comment: Is that so? I don't see it, where?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I removed it to create code more readable for people trying to understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an additional timer -

```
long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - blinkTimer) / 1000000;
    if(elapsed < 1000){
        //g.drawString("",x,y); Draw String Here
        breakTimer = System.nanoTime();
    }

    long breakElapsed = (System.nanoTime() - breakTimer) / 1000000;
    if(breakElapsed > 500){
        blinkTimer = System.nanoTime();
    }
```